# Unable to scrape particular data from a URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, phpquery

I want to scrape [this URL](https://weedmaps.com/deliveries/green-door-west).

I am using phpQuery library for this purpose.

I want to scrape `#weedmenuPane` from that link which contains some items and its prices.

Problem is, when I get scraped HTML, the required DIV is not in the scraped HTMl.

I have checked with Firebug but it is not coming from any AJAX call.

I thought it was coming by some kind of JS operation after HTML is loaded but I have also checked by disabling `JS` in my browser, and that DIV is there, means not coming by any JS operation.

I want to know how it is coming and how it is being generated.

Here is code I have tried.

```
 $html = file_get_contents($link, false, $context);
 $html = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($html);

 echo pq("",$html);

 echo pq("#weedmenuPane",$html)->html() . " here";
```

Comment: Please provide some of the code that already does part of what you described.

Comment: ok. i posted only relevent code ..... and `echo pq("",$html);` has whole page HTML in it but not the desired DIV in it ... and the second `echo` is empty obviusly

Comment: Just dump the html and look at it or connect through a Fiddler-style debug proxy.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have downloaded phpQuery and written a little test with your url.

This :

```
<?php

require 'phpQuery-onefile.php';

$url= "https://weedmaps.com/deliveries/green-door-west";
$HTML = file_get_contents($url);
$pq = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($HTML);
$div = pq('#weedmenuPane', $pq);
echo $div; // Content of #weedmenuPane
// or with your code
echo pq("#weedmenuPane", $pq)->html() . " here";
?>
```

Return the content of the #weedmenuPane DIV.

So try to use this code or show me your code and we will find your problem.